# Swift UITableview edit different values in textboxes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, edit

I apologize in advanced if this has already been asked but I can't find what I am looking for. So if you can point me in the right direction that will help.

So I have a `UIViewController` that will have a `UITableview` with 4 different cells. Each with different values and each cell will have 1 `UITextField` and 1 `UILabel`. I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that will allow me to edit or save the data. Eventually writing the new data to a database. my problem is I am not sure how to edit the data in the `UITextField`. I am not sure where to even begin. Below is a screen shot of what I described above. The left side has `UILabel` and the right is the `UITextfield`. The values will all be verified by another function to insure they are correct. I just want to change the value of the fields as needed then save the data. Not sure how to actually extract the values outside of cellForRowAt. Everything else is working, once I get this issue fixed I can get everything to work.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can store all cell in one array. When you want to access data of `UITextField` you can get all text fields from that array. You can give tag to `UITextField` like `textField.tag = indexPath.row`. So that you can add different condition for each `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using delegate from Cell to your VC(the one with TableView inside it).
When the textfield value changes, call your delegate and pass the cell and perhaps the string value inside the textfield. In your parent VC, you get the cell and you easily find the index of it and update your Model.

In your cell custom class

```
protocol ProtocolName{
  func  FunctionName(c:UITableViewCell,val:String)
}
...
var delegate:ProtocolName!
  @IBAction  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
       delegate.FunctionName(self,textfield.text)
    }
```

In your parent VC, make sure you conform yo ProtocolName, then

```
func  FunctionName(c:UITableViewCell,val:String){
    if let index = tableview.indexPath(for cell: c){
     // Update your model based on the index and val which is whatever is in the textfield of that cell. You can also reload data here
     }
}
```